# ngrx get value in function

Tags: observable, ngrx

I am unsure if this is the right thinking, but I just started using ngrx for a project and now everything is an observable. It works well when I use the async pipe in the component view, but I am struggeling when I need the value from the store in code. My current approach is to make a property and subscribe in the ngOnInit to the selector, so I can use the current value of the state in my functions. For example storing configration options (webservice address) and then using that inside a service.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    localOptions$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromOptions.selectLocalOptionsState));
    options: fromLocalOptions.State;


    constructor(
        private store: Store<fromOptions.State>,
    ) {
        this.localOptions$.subscribe(localOptions => this.options = localOptions);
    }


    getEntities (fParams): Observable<any> {
        console.log(this.options.webServiceUrl);
    }

}
```

This feels weird, so my question is: Is this the way to do it, or am I missing something, but everywhere I read that there is no easy way to get "the current value from observable" which I think I already understand why.

Comment: Yes, this is common in ngrx projects - to store commonly accessed selectors in services as Observables or realized values.I don't know why you or others think getting the value from an observable is not easy, `subscribe(val => ...)` whats hard about that?

Comment: It is hard to conceive that you have to wrap everything inside the subscribe function, which your year long training taught you to store in a variable that you use. And that you have to combine observables when you need more than one property inside a function. That is like eating with your left hand all of the sudden, if all your life you had to eat with your right hand. But thanks for clarifying.